# Xamarin Forms - IsClipedToBounds on a Grid does not work. Children views are still clipping

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, floating-action-button, clipping

I am building a simple keypad for an application and I want to use floating action buttons for the keys. I am laying them in a Grid with a label sitting over them to get the bellow affect.

[image]

As you can see, the grid is clipping the shadows despite having the IsClippedToBounds property set to false. I have searched around online and not found much about this. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Below is the XAML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:fab="clr-namespace:Refractored.FabControl;assembly=Refractored.FabControl"
x:Class="CauseMobileWalletMerchant.Views.KeypadView">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        Margin="0"
        IsClippedToBounds="false"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        RowSpacing="0"
        ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="75" />
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="75" />
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="75" />
            <ColumnDefinition
                Width="75" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="75" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="75" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="75" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="75" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="7"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            IsEnabled="true"
            HasShadow="true"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="8"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="9"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3"
            Margin="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="CLEAR"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="4"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="5"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="6"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="QR"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="1"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="2"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="3"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="FACE"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="0"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="00"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="2"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="-"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="22"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <fab:FloatingActionButtonView
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="3"
            ColorNormal="{DynamicResource Primary}"
            ColorPressed="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}"
            ColorRipple="{DynamicResource PrimaryDark}" />
        <Label
            Text="TOTAL"
            InputTransparent="true"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="12"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are drawing your shadowed buttons inside the Grid canvas. And every button is drawn inside its cell canvas. Its obvious that child wouldn't normally be drawn outside parent canvas.

The solution to you problem, without saying a usual "create a custom renderer" for the grid, is to draw every child over previous children. Then shadows will overlap like you want. So you would need to simulate cells: create a grid for being a container, every button will reside in cell 0,0, but with an appropriate Margin x,y - offsets for not overlapping other buttons. Create offsets at runtime, update them when parent size is changing and you will get it.